# Css transform with easing curve

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to animate element position using transform. How could I add some curve to this translate (nothing fancy, just not a full straight line)? With jquery I would use easeInSine which worked well.

```js
var a = document.querySelector('.a')
document.querySelector('.button').addEventListener('click', function() {

  var ww = window.innerWidth - (window.pageXOffset || document.documentElement.scrollLeft),
    wh = window.innerHeight - (window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop),
    rect = a.getBoundingClientRect(),

    final_left = ww - rect.left - a.offsetWidth,
    final_top = wh - rect.top - a.offsetHeight


  a.style.transform = "translate(" + final_left + "px," + final_top + "px)";


})
```

```css
.a {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  transition: all 0.4s;
}

.button {
  margin-left:100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">

</div>

<button class="button">
  run
</button>
```

Comment: Have you looked into the transition timing function e.g at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition-timing-function which describes the potential of using Beziere curves.

Comment: But I dont want to change animation time, I want it animate to final postion not in a straight line but on a curve.

Comment: I have misunderstood - you asked for it to be the same as jquery's easeInSine, which alters the timing function (not the overall time taken). Are you actually wanting to change the path rather than the timing function? What result do you get from easeInSine?

Comment: Yes, the path itself.

Comment: So not like jquery easeInSine.

Comment: @AHaworth - this is what made my animation curve:  element.animate({"left": [final_left+"px", 'easeInSine'], "top": final_top+"px"}, 400})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i know this is not possible with a single attribute like "transform".

For a circle motion you need to be able to set different transition-timings for your x-axis- and y-axis-movement. CSS can only do this if you use dedicated transition-attributes for both your x-movement and y-movement.

Since the transform-attribute cannot be split up like this you would need to change your code to use the "left" and "top" properties and add different transition-timings to each movement.

I updated your example in this fashion and the object now moves in a curved path.

```js
var a = document.querySelector('.a')
document.querySelector('.button').addEventListener('click', function() {

  var ww = window.innerWidth - (window.pageXOffset || document.documentElement.scrollLeft),
    wh = window.innerHeight - (window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop),
    rect = a.getBoundingClientRect(),

    final_left = ww - rect.left - a.offsetWidth,
    final_top = wh - rect.top - a.offsetHeight


    a.style.left = final_left + "px"  ;
    a.style.top = final_top + "px";


})
```

```css
.a {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  transition: top 0.8s ease-in, left 0.8s ease-out;
}

.button {
  margin-left:100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">

</div>

<button class="button">
  run
</button>
```

Comment: Can you change how much it curves?

Comment: Yes you can. I would encourage you to just play with the animation-timings for the top, and left property (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-timing-function). If you want to do fancy stuff like full circle motion look into the "cubic-bezier"-function. You could also first check out the math behind the motion, if you are not allergic to it ;), since it helps to reduce alot of trial and error in this process.

Comment: Yes, you just need to switch around the easings. (left->ease-in | top->ease-out). This way it would move counter-clockwise.

Answer (score 0):

Just add Border radius to it for example

```
.a {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 40px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  transition: all 0.4s;
}
```

I hope this will help you

Comment: I meant transition animation with curve, not border radius.

Comment: Ok maybe i got that, I think you should check out this site for better understanding  link:-https://tobiasahlin.com/blog/curved-path-animations-in-css/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

you can use `animate` for easeInSine method.see this how it works. its MDN web.
[here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/animate). for curve matters I'm not sure this can run as you want.

---

```js
var a = document.querySelector('.a')
document.querySelector('.button').addEventListener('click', function() {

  var ww = window.innerWidth - (window.pageXOffset || document.documentElement.scrollLeft),
    wh = window.innerHeight - (window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop),
    rect = a.getBoundingClientRect(),

    final_left = ww - rect.left - a.offsetWidth,
    final_top = wh - rect.top - a.offsetHeight


  a.style.transform = "translate(" + final_left + "px," + final_top + "px)";

   
})

   function goleft() {
   a.animate([ 

   { transform: "translateX(0px)" }, 
   { transform: "translateX(700px)" },

   { transform: "translateY(80px)" },
   { transform: "translateY(900px)" }


   ], { // timing options, more high numbers, the slower it will be
   duration: 1000, 
   easing: "ease-in-out", 
   fill: "both" 
   }); 

   }
```

```css
.a {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  transition: all 0.4s;
}

.button {
  margin-left:100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">

</div>

<button class="button">
  run
</button>

<button class="" onclick="goleft()">
  go buddy
</button>
```